# Check updated value in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am trying to write a oracle trigger to find updated value form a particular column of a table. I need to get that value, check the value and get another variable from a table. For an example.

let's say there is a table of employee attendance, it has attendance and employee, when updating attendance, need to get what is the updated value (is equal to 1) then what is the corresponding employee? (to do another process)

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7004.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this approach. In case of bulk updates (e.g You are updating multiply rows) try [the returning bulk collect into](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/returninginto_clause.htm#LNPLS01354) clause.

```
declare
   lv_Value varchar2(4000);
   li_EmpId employee.id%type;
begin
   -- updateing the attendance table.
   update attendance set value = 1 
   where <some_expression_defining_the_row_for_update>
   -- returning the updated value  and also the correspoinding employee id
   returning value, empid into lv_value, li_EmpId;
   -- doing another process
   do_another_porcess(lv_Value, li_EmpId);
end;
```

Hope this helps You.